# PPP over ttyUSB device

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, config

i have up ruining machine with Slackware 14.02 kernel 4.4.131

i want to compile my own kernel in to the machine, how ever i don't have the kernel .config file, so i'm using generic one from the Slackware website.

after the kernel boot i'm stack on the pppd proces that the device is runing, with the error massage:

> /usr/sbin/pppd:  unrecognized option 'ttyUSB2'
> pppd version 2.4.7

what seem that the pppd cannot open terminal over the ttyUSB2 connection. and that why i don't have keyboard. however at the builtin kernel the pppd is establishing connect and things working well

i tried to enable all the cnonfig of the ppp at the .config file

> CONFIG_PPP=y
> CONFIG_PPP_BSDCOMP=y
> CONFIG_PPP_DEFLATE=y
> CONFIG_PPP_FILTER=y
> CONFIG_PPP_MPPE=m
> CONFIG_PPP_MULTILINK=y
> CONFIG_PPPOATM=m
> CONFIG_PPPOE=y
> CONFIG_PPTP=m
> CONFIG_PPPOL2TP=m
> CONFIG_PPP_ASYNC=y
> CONFIG_PPP_SYNC_TTY=y

Thanks

Comment: `unrecognized option 'ttyUSB2'` `seem that the pppd cannot open terminal over the ttyUSB2 connection` no, it seems that the option is not recognized. You messed up with command line options or parameters in the script

Comment: hi @KamilCuk. which script?  i have touched any script. jest replaced the bzImage

Comment: Does /dev/ttyUSB2 exist in the machine? If so, perhaps it hadn't been created yet at the time when pppd was started.